# Can I Enter Sleep Mode While Downloading File?

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, macos

When I try to enter my rMBP into sleep mode while downloading file via iTunes U, the downloaded file is aborted. Is it possible to enter sleep mode while keep downloading the file?

EDIT: Until I find better option I put my display to sleep and not the computer. Check this to see how quickly enter this mode: [What Is the Keyboard Shortcut for Sleep Display Without Eject Key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59707/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-sleep-display)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you expect the download to continue while sleeping?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep downloading while sleeping.

Answer (score 4):

Have a Mac in sleep mode while also downloading a file with iTunes, is currently not possible.

However the idea is not out the question, doing things while in sleep is possible on certain new Mac hardware running OS X 10.8, via the new [Power Nap](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5394) feature.

What you asking to do is currently not a feature of Power Nap, however it is something that might be possible with a hack or a future version of  [Power Nap](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5394).

Therefore Power Nap can **only** do the following:

> **When your compatible Mac goes to sleep in Mountain Lion, Power Nap still gets things done silently**
>
> - Mail. Receive new messages.
> - Contacts. Your Contacts update with any changes you may have made on another device.
> - Calendar. Receive new invitations and calendar updates.
> - Reminders. Reminders updates with any changes you may have made on another device.
> - Notes. Notes updates with any changes you may have made on another device.
> - Documents in your iCloud account. iCloud pushes any edits you made to a document to your Mac notebook.
> - Photo Stream. Your Photo Stream updates with new photos from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.
> - Mac App Store updates. Your Mac notebook can download updates from the Mac App Store.
> - Time Machine backup. Your Mac notebook can back up while it sleeps.
> - Find My Mac. Locate a lost Mac notebook even when it’s sleeping.
> - VPN on demand. Corporate email updates securely.
> - Configuration profile. Macs in managed environments can receive configuration profile updates.
>
> **Power Nap does more when your Mac is plugged in to an AC outlet**
>
> When your portable Mac is connected to a power source, it also downloads software updates, makes backups with Time Machine, performs Spotlight indexing, and can continue Mac App Store downloads.  It also updates Help Center.

Comment: Yep, I too think PowerNap will allow it, especially for iTunes as it part of OS X.

Comment: Seems to only work for Mac App Store downloads currently, not for iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your computer to sleep all processing (including downloads) is stopped -> so no, you can't do that.

Putting the display to sleep (as mentioned in the question) is possible though.

Answer (score 2):

No, BUT if you go to System Preferences > Energy Saver and then change the computer sleep to "never" you can technically download when "sleeping". You can change the screen sleep to whatever you want.

Have a rMBP to and I do this when I'm downloading a huge file that takes more than 30 minutes to download.

Comment: Yep, that's my solution too.