# What Is the Keyboard Shortcut for Sleep Display Without Eject Key?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I read that if you want to put your display into sleep the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd>, but what is it in Mountain Lion or Lion using a retina MacBook Pro or MacBook Air without an eject button?

Comment: The combination 'control-eject' is a shortcut for 'power'.  (ADB keyboards had a real power button, but virtually none of Apple's USB/BT keyboards do.)  So 'control-shift-eject' seems like it should be the same as 'shift-power'.  Does that combo work for you?

Comment: Is there anything in this question that isn't covered here: [Is there a similarly fast alternative to Crtl + Shift + Eject for new Macbook Air?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/) Also relevant are [What's the purpose of the eject button on the MacBook Air?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5736/) and [Put the display to sleep without putting the whole computer to sleep?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27279/)

Comment: @bmike It's probably a duplicate of the first one, but the second one is misleading for owners on 2011 or 2012 Airs and this question is only covered in an answer in the third.

Comment: @Ken Shift+Power combo doesn't work.

Comment: Since Mavericks (10.9), just the Power button sleeps the display (does not put the computer to sleep).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

(At least on the Retina display MacBook Pro) use the Power button the same as you previously used the Eject button. So <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> puts the display to sleep and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> puts the machine to sleep.

Comment: At any rate, this is the best answer.

Comment: @CajunLuke I agree, but my money is on this [other question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5736/) being the best question.

Comment: Strangely, this seems to deactivate my USB network adapter at the same time.

Comment: Since Mavericks, just the Power button sleeps the display (without putting the computer to sleep).

Answer (score 4):

Found two options:

1. Use BetterTouchTool add global keyboard shortcut and choose Sleep Display.
2. Use Hot Corners (System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver) and choose Put Display To Sleep. (You can hold down <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and then it will only work when you're in the selected corner and while <kbd>⌘</kbd> is pressed.)

Comment: Hrrm... Call me crazy, but I *think* that's one option.  ;)

Comment: Ah, there you go.

Comment: WOW. I didn't know that a 'Put display to Sleep' even existed. I think Command ⌘ + Hot Corner is the way to go. The Mac is so AWESOME. :D

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution to get the same functionality as the previous model (The model with the <kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> button).

The same thing can be achieved by replacing the <kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd> button with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> button.

<kbd>Control ^</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>: Turns off your screen

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>: Put Macbook to Sleep

All other solutions involved a third party software, a new shortcut or did not work.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/19115443#19115443

Answer (score 0):

[Found a solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4083883?start=0&tstart=0) over at the Apple Support Communities:

> I just found out that pressing the function (fn) key and the power button calls up a dialog box where you can choose to sleep or shut down (shut down is the default when you press return.

Give it a shot!

Comment: sleep the computer or display?

Comment: This only allows the user to sleep the computer, not the display.  Also, on a sidenote, it doesn't matter whether you press fn or not – the power button does the same thing.  At least, that's true for me on 10.8.

Comment: That one I'm not entirely sure on. The post over there comes to an abrupt end after the solution is posted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [short program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239439/command-to-sleep-display-osx) on StackOverflow which uses a "semi-undocumented api" to put all displays to sleep.

Putting this in Automator should allow you to hook it to a global keyboard shortcut, I think.

Answer (score -1):

you can hold the power button for a little more than 1 second!!

Comment: and this will put the display to sleep?

Answer (score -3):

The difference between putting the display to sleep and putting the computer to sleep might be important to some users:

- <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Eject ⏏</kbd> puts the display to sleep
- <kbd>Opt-Cmd-Eject ⏏</kbd> puts the whole computer to sleep

Putting only the display to sleep allows any running programs (including large downloads that are in progress) to continue while you lock your screen (if you have it set to require a password) and leave the computer, while putting the whole computer to sleep will stop a download's progress as soon as you put it to sleep.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about how to put the display to sleep **without** the eject key (not present on devices without an optical drive)