# Shut Down or Reboot Your RETINA Mac with a Keyboard Command

Tags: macbook-pro

I have seen a shortcut to shutdown mac using key combinations. It includes the use of <kbd>eject</kbd> key. But since retina macbooks dont have eject key how do I shutdown/reboot the retina mac.
This [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59707/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-sleep-display-without-eject-key) is having query regarding puting it to sleep but I cannot see shutdown/reboot. Is pressing power button and selecting the choice the only option I have ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the <kbd>power</kbd> button in place of <kbd>eject</kbd> for any keyboard shortcut that worked with <kbd>eject</kbd> (this also applies to older MacBooks, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

To gracefully and quickly initiate a shutdown of a retina mac (or any mac that doesn't have a media eject key) press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> (to display the shutdown dialogue box) you can then release those keys and, since shutdown is the default selected option, just press <kbd>return</kbd> to shutdown the mac.

To restart gracefully press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>. Again, this will pull up the shutdown dialogue box but you will have to mouse over to the restart option to select it. This isn't a true 'keyboard shortcut' but I am not aware of one existing.

For many keyboard shortcuts you can use the power button in place of eject, but for the shutdown and restart commands doing so will initiate a hard shutdown/restart and you may loose data.

Note: The <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> key combination is the same as holding down <kbd>power</kbd> and waiting ~2 seconds for the shutdown menu dialogue to appear.